# Artifactory - randomly add datetime to artifact name

Tags: maven, azure-devops, artifactory

From Azure CI pipeline I can see that before the build/artifact upload to Artifactory, the artifact id is

```
my-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

however after Artifactory upload, it becomes

```
my-app-0.0.1-20211006.161121-1.jar
```

But another Java project don't have such behavior hence no extra data/timestamp in the artifact name.

I assume the pipeline only upload the jar file without check the pom.xml, so what can be the cause of such difference in the naming convension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When SNAPSHOTs are uploaded to Nexus or Artifactory, the suffix `SNAPSHOT` is automatically replaced by a timestamp and a number.

This is perfectly normal and nothing to worry about.

Comment: @J Fabian Meier Thanks. Well but I see other application also have `-SNAPSHOT` suffix but weren't replace with timestamp and a number, so wondering what could be the variable of such difference, esp. running in a pipeline (i.e. by JFrog etc)

Comment: If you deploy through Maven, the `-SNAPSHOT` will always be replaced. If this is not the case, then you need to ask a new question about the specific situation.